# Add Value to Azure App Configuration using Pulumi

Tags: c#, azure, pulumi

I created an App Configuration using Pulumi:

```
 _configurationStore = new ConfigurationStore(appConfigurationName, new ConfigurationStoreArgs
            {
                ResourceGroupName = _resourceGroup.Name,
                Location = _resourceGroup.Location,
                Sku = "standard"
            });
```

Now I am stuck adding values to it. The docs don't mention any method to read or write settings into my ConfigurationStore (or I simply cannot find it).

How can I store simple key/value-Pairs?
How can I store "links" to values from an existing keyvault? Do I simply create the connectionstring manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding key-values was introduced by Azure Resource Manager (ARM) just recently in the `2020-07-01-preview` version and there's no "stable" API version with them yet. So, you should use that version to define key-values

```
new Pulumi.AzureNextGen.AppConfiguration.V20200701Preview.KeyValue("kv",
    new Pulumi.AzureNextGen.AppConfiguration.V20200701Preview.KeyValueArgs
    {
        ResourceGroupName = _resourceGroup.Name,
        ConfigStoreName = _configurationStore.Name,
        KeyValueName = "key1",
        Value = "value1",
    });
```

You can read more in the docs: https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/azure-nextgen/appconfiguration/keyvalue/

Also, discussed in this issue: https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-azure-nextgen/issues/62

Comment: I had this working a few days ago around the time this was posted (non-related to this post). Today I suddenly started getting " error: cannot check existence of resource" when adding key values. I've tested this against 3 different subscriptions with full permissions. Not sure what changed... any ideas?

Comment: Discussed in https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-azure-nextgen/issues/298